# Message box on close only show when text is changed

Tags: vba, vb.net

So I take no credit to the following code as it was given to me by another fellow user and don't get me wrong it works great but now I only Want the message box to show when text is changed in textboxes and if all text boxes are empty to just close the app when the X is clicked.

Any help is appreciated!

```
'Creates _handle as boolean
Private _handle As Boolean = True

Private Sub MainWindow_Closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing

    'Creates a messagebox to ask if the user wants to exit the application or no. If yes application closes, if no then application stays open
    If _handle = True Then
        e.Cancel = True

        Dim result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question)
        If (result = MessageBoxResult.Yes) Then
            _handle = False
            Environment.Exit(0)
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: add a "dirty" flag that gets set if anything changes. you may be able to attach the same handler to all textboxes or other elements

Comment: I am quite new to vb how does one do a "dirty" flag?

Comment: a boolean variable that you set to indicate that something changed. your _handle could be called a flag in that it gets set somewhere else in code, and you take action based on whether _handle is tru or false. you could just re-use the handle variable and set it to true when data in relevant fields changed.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38756/Two-Simple-Approaches-to-WinForms-Dirty-Tracking

Comment: Just don't write code like this, your user is sure 99.99% of the time.  If the 0.01% case causes data loss then fix that problem instead.

Comment: @Jeremy thank you much my friend!

Comment: Don't use `Environment.Exit(0)` in an event that's designed to close anyway. This is the second time I've seen this today.

Comment: Your question has little to do with the code you supplied: `I only Want the message box to show when text is changed in textboxes and if all text boxes are empty to just close`